# set event listener that executes only on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, publish-subscribe

I have a coffee function that publishes to PubSub and also appends created element to a list here it is

```
handle_comments = ->  
  commentId = $('.question_comments').data('commentId')  
  PrivatePub.subscribe commentId, (data, channel) ->        
     res = $.parseJSON(data.comment_res.comment)
     result = JST["templates/create_comment"]
       user_name: data.comment_res.user 
       comment_body: res.body 
       comment_id: res.id
     $('.question_errors').html("")  
     $('.comments_list').append(result)
     $('.new_comment').find('#comment_body').val('')    

 $(document).ready(handle_comments)||$(document).on('page:load',      handle_comments)||$(document).on('page:update', handle_comments)
```

Now I have a problem that this function executes every time I'm changing smth on a page( like deleting a node or else). I need a way to set it executing only when creating a comment. 
p.s. handlers ready,page:load and page:update are set to avoid problems with turbolinks. Sorry for my poor English. Would be grateful for every single advice

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way out I found, is to set a flag in controller action

```
    PrivatePub.publish_to "/questions/#{@commentable.id}/comments", comment_res: { comment: @comment.to_json, user: current_user.name, **method: self.action_name** }
```

or even less complex executable: true (a bit similar to remote: true :)  )
If you do know some other variants, I would be very curious to see them